# Why use ~ between x and y axis column selections rather than the conventional plot(x,y ) in plot(x,y, xlab, ylab) seen in R documentation?

Tags: r, plot

So what I have gathered is that the ~ reverts the values to their correct values seeing as how height is originally in the 10's and later in the 100's. However, the same can be achieved by the III) below. Looks to be like some extra unnecessary feature. In what occasions would this be helpful that is worth having it built-in.

```
I)plot(survey$Height~survey$Wr.Hnd, xlab="Writing Handspan (cm)", ylab = "Height (cm)")
```

vs

```
II)plot(survey$Height,survey$Wr.Hnd, xlab="Writing Handspan (cm)", ylab = "Height (cm)")
```

vs

```
III) plot(survey$Wr.Hnd,survey$Height , xlab="Writing Handspan (cm)", ylab = "Height (cm)")
```

Part of the data:

```
 Sex Wr.Hnd NW.Hnd W.Hnd    Fold Pulse    Clap Exer Smoke Height      M.I    Age
1  Female   18.5   18.0 Right  R on L    92    Left Some Never 173.00   Metric 18.250
2    Male   19.5   20.5  Left  R on L   104    Left None Regul 177.80 Imperial 17.583
3    Male   18.0   13.3 Right  L on R    87 Neither None Occas     NA     <NA> 16.917
4    Male   18.8   18.9 Right  R on L    NA Neither None Never 160.00   Metric 20.333
5    Male   20.0   20.0 Right Neither    35   Right Some Never 165.00   Metric 23.667
6  Female   18.0   17.7 Right  L on R    64   Right Some Never 172.72 Imperial 21.000
7    Male   17.7   17.7 Right  L on R    83   Right Freq Never 182.88 Imperial 18.833
8  Female   17.0   17.3 Right  R on L    74   Right Freq Never 157.00   Metric 35.833
9    Male   20.0   19.5 Right  R on L    72   Right Some Never 175.00   Metric 19.000
10   Male   18.5   18.5 Right  R on L    90   Right Some Never 167.00   Metric 22.333
```

Comment: The `~` notation is also in the documentation, see `?plot.formula`, it's also linked to in the generic `?plot` documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main application would be for brevity/readability when the `data` argument is specified:

```
 plot(Height~Wr.Hnd, data=survey, ...)
```